# How to get webpack js file correctly in django?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, django-webpack-loader

I think my problem is more or less a simple question, but I'm not still accustomed to using webpack and so on, So your advice will be helpful to me. (I'm using Django on backend and React on frontend)

**Hierarchy of folder**

```
Cebula4
    -  back
         - settings.py
         - manage.py
    -  front
         - static
             - bundles
                  - MainPage.js (webpacked)
```

**Settings.py**

```
...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

...
```

How can I get this webpack file(MainPage.js) in output folder like `C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula4\front\static\bundles\MainPage.js` by `local web_url` like http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bundles...?

Comment: `C:\Users\1Sun\Cebula4\front\static\bundles\MainPage.js` is not an URL.  Try setting `STATIC_ROOT` to `/static/`.

Comment: @RedCricket you mean that I need to replace `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')` ?